# Returning and reading objects in asp.net web service and windows forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, web, service

```
 public class VremeZip : IXmlSerializable
    {
        string naziv;
        string temperatura;
        string zemljevid_url;

        public void SetNaziv(string n)
        {
            naziv = n;
        }
        public void SetTemperatura(string n)
        {
            temperatura = n;
        }
        public void SetZemlj(string n)
        {
            zemljevid_url = n;
        }
        public string GetNaziv()
        {
            return naziv;
        }

        XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("string", naziv);
            writer.WriteElementString("string", temperatura);
            writer.WriteElementString("string", zemljevid_url);

        }
    }
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public VremeZip Vreme(string zip)
        {
            cdyne.Weather v1 = new cdyne.Weather();
            VremeZip v = new VremeZip();
            v.SetNaziv(v1.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).City);
            v.SetTemperatura(v1.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).Temperature);
            v.SetZemlj("ni urlja");





            // return v1.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).Temperature;
            return v;
        }
    }
```

This is my asp.net web service code, which returns an object of VremeZip class, it consists of 3 strings.

Now, I have created a c# windows forms app, and I want to read that object, and display all of the information provided.

I have a textbox, and a button with click event:

```
public class VremeZip
        {
            public string naziv { get; set; }
            public string temperatura { get; set; }
            public string zemljevid_url { get; set; }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vreme.WebService1 v1 = new vreme.WebService1();
            VremeZip v = new VremeZip();
            label1.Text = v1.Vreme(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

However, this will only return the first thing. For example, if I enter 90001 (Los Angeles zip code), it will return just the city in my label, instead of all three strings (name, temperature, url).

I can't create a new object in my windows forms and just do:

```
VremeZip v = new VremeZip();
v = v1.Vreme(textBox1.Text);
```

Since I get an error, because somehow my method returns string, not the actual object.

Is it somehow possible to get all 3 strings from the object?

Comment: Firstly, you have `VremeZip` class declared in your winforms code. You also have it inheriting `IXmlSerializable`, which is it? To get a combined string, create a `ToString()` override in your `VremeZip` class.

Comment: IXmlSerializable is just the class to serialize it, since asp.net web service returns xml code.

For example, if I return a string, just the temperature:

return v1.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip).Temperature;

It will return <string>"Temperature"</string>

Comment: So basically, if it returns the object as it does now, it will return 
<string>CityName</string> //Naziv
<string>Temperature</string>
<string>zemljevid_url></string>

I'm trying to get all the info from it into my class in winforms

Comment: As I have stated, use a `ToString()` override method in your class to return back `naziv + " " + temperatura + " " + zemljevid_url`

Comment: I could override the toString method, but I want it to return an object, not just one string.

Comment: You asked to *get all 3 strings from the object* from the question, and now you're stating you *want it to return an object* as per previous comment.

Comment: I might have been unclear, sorry. I want my web service to RETURN an object (which consists of 3 strings), then I want to get the data from those strings in my windows forms app.

Comment: the two classes `VremeZip` are distinctly different, one in the winforms class, and the other in the web service,instantiating  `VremeZip v = new VremeZip();` and assigning it to `v`is different to what this method `v1.Vreme(textBox1.Text);` returns.  This is in your winforms code, by the way. Its like one class has overlaid the other. think about it for a moment.

Comment: Uhm, the thing is, if I use the method Vreme, which is my method in web service, it returns a STRING, when it should return an object. I'm very confused, as the classes are the same, both consist of 3 strings.. I might just do it all in 1 string, and stick it in a label..

Comment: One class is a standalone and inherits the default `Object`, the other implements `IXmlSerializable`, try this, rename the class definition in the winforms app code to `VremeZipA`, does the code pick up the class definition from the webservice?

Comment: It's a totally different project, that's why the class is redefined. I wanted to something like: 

VremeZip v = new VremeZip();
v = v1.Vreme(textBox1.Text);

Then get v.naziv, v.temperatura, etc.

Comment: **the class is redefined**, there's your confusion.

Comment: So I somehow need to define it in a seperate file, then add a reference to it in both projects? The thing that bothers me still is that it says that the method returns string, not an object..

Comment: correct! define it in separate project or dll, ad reference to it in both projects.

Comment: It still bothers me that it says in c# that the method Vreme returns string, while it returns object. Wouldn't it say that it returns an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip t0mm13b, I didn't manage to return the whole object, I just override the tostring method and returned one string. From then, I split the string into seperate pieces.